# Can someone help me understand how these programs work? Have just started programming

Tags: python

```
**1**
count = 0
phrase = "hello, world"
for iteration in range(5):
    index = 0
    while index < len(phrase):
        count += 1
        index += 1
    print "Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count)


**2**
count = 0
phrase = "hello, world"
for iteration in range(5):
    while True:
        count += len(phrase)
        break
    print "Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count)

**3**
count = 0
phrase = "hello, world"
for iteration in range(5):
    count += len(phrase)
    print "Iteration " + str(iteration) + "; count is: " + str(count)
```

Comment: They are a little strange examples.. Have you run them? what do they do? what do you expect them to do?

Comment: Yes they basically count the number of letters in the phrase and print the count on each iteration. But I do not understand the concept that is being applied. I hope you understand what I am trying to convey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 1: There is a `count` variable to store a number, and the phrase `"hello, world"` stored in the `phrase` variable. The for loop repeats 5 times. Inside it, a placeholder variable `index` is defined. Repeating the while loop the length of `phrase` times, the placeholder `index` and the `count` variable are increased by one. The last line of the for loop prints out which round of the for loop it in and the `count` variable.

Number 2: Again, the `count` and `phrase` variables are defined. Repeating the for loop 5 times, the first line creates an infinite while loop (one that repeats forever). However, after `count` is increased by the length of `phrase`, it immediately `break`s out of the while loop (stops it) so that it does not continue forever. The last line prints out the same thing as Number 1 does. (This might be clear due to the fact that they are identical lines of code.)

Number 3: The `count` and `phrase` variables are defined once more. 5 times the for loop is run. Each time, `count` is increased by the length of `phrase`, and then the `print` statement is run (same as numbers 1 and 2).

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Mr.Python: Yes, it does run up to but not include the number passed in (`range(4)` runs up to 4). However, since the `range()` function by default starts at 0, not 1, so the loop would go from 0 to 4, which is 5 repetitions.